# Install4J version unpacking fails

Tags: java, install4j

We are using `Install4J` version for creating an installer. During install, install4j throws the below exception during unpacking. Because of this the `jar` files bundled is  getting extracted partially (size and cheksum both doesn't match) and the application is not working.

**How to debug this issue ?**

I started install with the flag

```
-Dinstall4j.debug=true -Dinstall4j.logToStderr=true
```

but it's not giving much information and we use Java 8 and Ubuntu

```
java.io.IOException: null ref
    at com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.NativeUnpack.getNextFile(Native Method)
    at com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.NativeUnpack.run(NativeUnpack.java:215)
    at com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.NativeUnpack.run(NativeUnpack.java:247)
    at com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.UnpackerImpl.unpack(UnpackerImpl.java:138)
    at com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.UnpackerImpl.unpack(UnpackerImpl.java:174)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.Unpacker.unpack(Unpacker.java:55)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerContextImpl.unpackAdditionalUserFiles(InstallerContextImpl.java:265)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerContextImpl.checkStart(InstallerContextImpl.java:230)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.start(Controller.java:59)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.runInProcess(Installer.java:41)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Installer.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:62)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:57)
```

[INFO] `com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RequestPrivilegesAction` [ID 13]: Execute action

Answer (score 0):

The Pack200 decompression fails for one of the JAR files in the "Installer->Custom Code & Resources" list.

You may need to unjar it and jar it again.

Contact support@ej-technologies.com for a build that prints the name of the file where the unpacking fails.